# Possible bug in the "since" key, or it supposed to work like this?

Tags: datetime, facebook-graph-api

I'm querying the facebook feeds to get the latest feeds. I'm using the FB api:

```
 55xxxxx/feed?since=1323269266&date_format=U&limit=5
```

The since date is taken from the previous api call first object create_date. Now the problem is that if the Group/News (id :55xxxxx) the first object's create_date is still 1323269266. It will give me again the 5 feeds. But I would like it to give me any new feeds after 1323269266. Any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a combination of `since` and `until` parameters rather than just `since`.

Comment: so it needs to be since="last object date created" and until="last object date created" ? or other logic?

Comment: anything your requirements say

Comment: well logically how can i do it if i like to get the latest 10

Comment: `&limit=10`  as facebook always gives the latest ones first

Comment: Maybe you're typing it in wrong.  When I do `me/feed?limit=1` in the Graph API Explorer tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), I get the latest one.  If I do `me/feed?limit=2`, I get the latest two, if I do `me/feed?limit=3` I get the latest 3. If I do `me/feed?limit=10` I get the latest 10